# How to make a slider to slide across columns to visualize data using plotly and pycountry

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, pycountry-convert

I am trying to create a visual to show country wise GDP across years. My dataframe contains data from 1980 to 2013. A small (made-up) sample of it is here:

```
Country|1980 YR1980|1981 YR1981|1982 YR 1982|...
     A | 1         |  -        |   2        |...
     B | -         |  1        |   2.5      |...
     c | -         |  0.433    |   4.7      |...
```

```js
import plotly.express as px
#!pip install pycountry
import pycountry

list_countries = df['Country'].unique().tolist()
d_country_code = {}  # To hold the country names and their ISO
for country in list_countries:
    try:
        country_data = pycountry.countries.search_fuzzy(country)
        # country_data is a list of objects of class pycountry.db.Country
        # The first item  ie at index 0 of list is best fit
        # object of class Country have an alpha_3 attribute
        country_code = country_data[0].alpha_3
        d_country_code.update({country: country_code})
    except:
        print('could not add ISO 3 code for ->', country)
        # If could not find country, make ISO code ' '
        d_country_code.update({country: ' '})
for k, v in d_country_code.items():
    df.loc[(df.Country == k), 'iso_alpha'] = v

fig = px.choropleth(data_frame = df,
                    locations= "iso_alpha",
                    color= "1980",  # value in column 'Confirmed' determines color
                    hover_name= "Country",
                    color_continuous_scale= 'RdYlGn',  #  color scale red, yellow green
                    #animation_frame= "df.iloc()"
                    )

fig.show()
```

When I am using this code block above, I can visualise data for 1980 but I want to set animation frame so that I can visualize data across years every 5 years. And colors are set by GDP in the specific year column.

How can I achieve my goal.

Do I need to make a list of the columns from 1980 to 2013 and pass them?

Can anyone please help me? Also - if anyone has any other python libraries to suggest that is welcome a well.

Comment: Try one of the examples from this [link](https://plotly.com/python/animations/). If you print out the data frame used in these examples, you should see that the animation frame should just be ONE of the columns and there there are duplicate countries (e.g. USA 1980 USA 1981 ... and so on for all countries)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link - although I have seen this already. But the thing is - we donot get to choose how our data should look like when we get it from the source. Now - my question is - since I have years spread across multiple columns how to create the visualization for that.